# z index is not working after using rotateY

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a page flip effect. for this I need two `div` overlapped. In my structure both divs are originally by side and second `div` is given `-webkit-rotateY(180deg)`. `z-index` of first div is 2 and second div is 1. So first div should be overlapping second div.

Issue is, even though z index of second div is less than the first div, second div is appearing above the first div. How can I fix this? I am using safari 5.1.7.

HTML-

```
<body>
<div id="BookMainDiv" class="BookMainDiv">
<div id="CoverPage" class="CoverPage">
</div>
<div id="LastPage" class="LastPage">
</div>          
</div>
</body>
```

CSS-

```
    .CoverPage{
position:absolute;
height:80%;
width:35%;
top:12%;
left:50%;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:2;
-webkit-transform-origin : 0% 0%;  
-webkit-transition:transform  1s ease-in-out;
background:orange;
}

.LastPage{
position:absolute;
height:80%;
width:35%;
top:12%;
left:15%;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1;
background:blue;
-webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
```

}

Comment: I don't know about Safari, but with Chromium 25, it works as expected. The orange div is above the blue one.

Comment: Yea it works in chrome, even for me.

Comment: You can check this link, I think it will help you to solve your problem. 

http://w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

Is #bookmaindiv position relative? If not try that.